# What are the meanings of *cast* and *conversion*?

Tags: c++, casting, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between type casting & type conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374325/is-there-any-difference-between-type-casting-type-conversion)

I personally use the terms *cast* and *conversion* interchangeably. Is that correct? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Strictly, pedantically, they are not the same.  But people do it all the time.

Comment: This is a dupe of a question with an answer by coppro.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374325/is-there-any-difference-between-type-casting-type-conversion

Comment: @John btw I agree that C++'s usage of "cast" is a bit nasty (it overloads the term imho), but I think that it is sufficiently narrow to say that "cast" means "explicit type conversion" (i.e "casting away const", "cast notation" etc.. is all about explicit type conversions). What some people say casts are is actually called "type-pun", as said by 5.2.10/10. Good that C is much more clearer than C++. It has a clear and concise definition of "cast".

Comment: Note that `reinterpret_cast<int*>(some_char_ptr)` is not a type-pun: It still interprets the pointer as a `char*` when reading its value. A type-pun would look like `reinterpret_cast<int*&>(some_char_ptr)` or `*reinterpret_cast<int**>(&some_char_ptr)`. This will read the value of the pointer as an `int*`. Of course, both of these type-puns are undefined behavior.

Comment: @litb:  concurred.  This is a surprisingly hard question to answer well.  @others: litb & I are continuing a discussion we started in our now-deleted posts

Answer (score 3):

Conversion entails construction of type A from an instance of a different type B.

Casting entails use of one or other of the multifarious C++ casting operators, or a C-style cast.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they're the same -- a cast causes the compiler to perform an explicit conversion, but you can have implicit conversions too, e.g.

```
double d = 23; // implicit conversion from int to double
```

Versus:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(23.0); // explicit conversion from double to int
```

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `double` to `int` in C++.

Comment: @James: Badly chosen example in that case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion implies the taking of a value of a specific type and performing some function to provide a representation in another type. Casting simply says "assume this data is in this new type". Some casts implicitly cause conversions, so I think it's a little interchangeable.

Comment: Casting can cause a conversion to happen, though -- it's not just a question of assuming that the data is in the new type. In the example I gave above, 23.0 gets converted to an int before being stored in i.

Comment: @sgolodetz - hence my last sentence about some casts implying (to the compiler) that a conversion should occur.

Comment: Not correct in the context of C and C++.

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't read it carefully enough. I think the second last sentence is misleading though.

Comment: (And I don't think they're a little interchangeable.)

Comment: @sgolodetz I think if some casts cause conversions, and some conversions are simply copy and casts, then the terms exist along a murky gradient. If I'm wrong about either of those two things, then I would be incorrect in implying a crossover of terminology.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb you've definitely got a lot more C/C++ experience than me, care to share what I've gotten wrong in my answer?

Comment: @sgolodetz, I think my second sentence is a little misleading - I perhaps should specify `reinterpret_cast` there, but I'm not sure that would be clear or correct.

Comment: @jball: If you're being informal about it, then it's probably ok I guess :) But casts are a language construct used to ask the compiler to perform a conversion that it wouldn't perform implicitly. So the terms are related, but not interchangeable. (Saying they're interchangeable is like saying that asking for pizza and getting pizza are the same thing. Just not true in my experience ;) Even if the two do exist along a murky gradient...) The thing's also complicated by the special casts C++ provides, e.g. dynamic_cast.

Comment: @jball (again): If you'd said `reinterpret_cast` there, I think I'd have complained less :) Whether I should complain less in that situation I'll leave as an open question...

Comment: @sgolodetz Constructive complaining is always a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

A cast is a special type of conversion.  Another type is that performed by functions like atoi and itoa, and the string streams.  Still another type would be something like this:

```
int minutes_to_seconds(int minutes) { return minutes * 60; }
```