# Correct c++-style cast for fixed size arrays?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I have a small question regarding casts.

Basically, I have the following code :

```
//Array of ALbyte, size is irrelevant
ALbyte buffer[1000];
//...
alcCaptureSamples(m_audioDevice,(ALCvoid*)buffer, sample);
```

and based on Scott Meyers Effective C++ advice, I'd like to use a c++-style cast for this.

But I don't really know which one I should pick between `reinterpret_cast<ALCvoid*>` and `static_cast<ALCvoid*>`. They say on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that `reinterpret_cast` is used for converting a pointer to another pointer type.

But in Effective C++, I read

> `reinterpret_cast` is intended for low-level casts that yield implementation-dependent (i.e. unportable) results, e.g., casting a pointer to an int

and that these should be very rare.

Then, which cast should I pick ? I obviously eliminated `const_cast` and `dynamic_cast` but can't determine which of the remaining I should use... (and this question didn't really help me as I don't know if the fact that I want to cast a fixed size array into a pointer types from OpenAL impacts or not).

Or should I completely avoid the C++-style cast in this case (but why) ?

Comment: Maybe [this SO question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you probably *don't* need to do any casting.

Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers, and that all pointers can be implicitly casted to `void*` (which I guess `ALCvoid*` is).

Comment: This might be a bit nit-picky, but wouldn't it be clearer to say "implicitly converted" (if you don't need to do any [*casting*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374325/is-there-any-difference-between-type-casting-type-conversion)). +1 nevertheless

Comment: Indeed... I don't know why but I thought that it feels wrong not to make the cast (or rather "conversion") explicit (as it was to `ACLvoid*` and not to pure `void*`)...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `static_cast` whenever possible as it performs compile-time checks: the compiler will not let you cast to an invalid pointer type.

`reinterpret_cast` cannot perform any compile time checks other than `const` to `non-const`. It's rarely used unless programming with older interfaces requiring `void*`.

Better still though is to design your code so you don't need to do casting: exploting polymorphism can help you avoid them.

Comment: Well in this case I think I can't really avoid that and redesign (though I'd like to), because of the types OpenAL requests in its functions...